# Is there any public paper/algorithm that categorize similar human faces to different groups like google Picasa does?

Tags: picasa, face-recognition

Is there any public paper/algorithm that categorize similar human faces to different groups like google Picasa does?

For example I have many photos with human faces, and I do no tagging on them, the algorithm can extract some features from these faces, it calculates something like similarity score or feature vector distance and put similar faces to groups.

Searched around, it seems the algorithm Picasa has is not public. Could anyone share me some light? Thanks very much.